# Postgresql dynamic Update Query Execution

Tags: postgresql, dynamic

I have a plpgsql block which generates a dynamic update query  as :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_lenght_test () RETURNS VOID AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
    /*
    some code here
    */
    dyn_sql = 'UPDATE';
                            IF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8)   = 'pro_ans' THEN
                                dyn_sql = dyn_sql ||    ' profile_answers ';
                            ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'reg_ans' THEN
                                 dyn_sql = dyn_sql ||    ' reg_answers ';
                            ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'tvl_ans' THEN
                                dyn_sql = dyn_sql ||    ' tvl_answers ';
                            END IF;

                                dyn_sql = dyn_sql|| 'SET' || ' ' || que_col_name || ' = ' || NEW_VALUE_FOR_COLUMN ;

                                dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' WHERE' ;

                            IF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'pro_ans' THEN
                                dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' pro_ans_frn_pro_id = (SELECT pro_ans_frn_pro_id FROM profile_answers JOIN registrations ON (pro_ans_frn_pro_id = reg_frn_pro_id) WHERE reg_id ';
                            ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'reg_ans' THEN
                                dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' reg_answers WHERE reg_ans_frn_reg_id ';
                            ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'tvl_ans' THEN
                                dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' tvl_answers WHERE tvl_ans_frn_reg_id ';
                            END IF;

                            IF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'pro_ans' THEN  
                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql || '= ' || CAST(temp_reg AS VARCHAR) || ');';
                            ELSE
                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql || '= ' || CAST(temp_reg AS VARCHAR) || ';';

 /* want to execute this update dynamic query */
/*
some code here

*/
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Can you please help me executing this dynamic Update query .
Thanks In advance.

Comment: What is the postgresql version?

Answer (score 1):

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_lenght_test () 
RETURNS VOID AS
 $BODY$

```
DECLARE
dyn_sql varchar;
BEGIN
/*
some code here
*/
dyn_sql = 'UPDATE';
                 IF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8)   = 'pro_ans' THEN
                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql ||    ' profile_answers ';
                  ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'reg_ans' THEN
                             dyn_sql = dyn_sql ||    ' reg_answers ';
                  ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'tvl_ans' THEN
                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql ||    ' tvl_answers ';
                  END IF;

                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql|| 'SET' || ' ' || que_col_name || ' = ' || NEW_VALUE_FOR_COLUMN ;

                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' WHERE' ;

                        IF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'pro_ans' THEN
                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' pro_ans_frn_pro_id = (SELECT pro_ans_frn_pro_id FROM profile_answers JOIN registrations ON (pro_ans_frn_pro_id = reg_frn_pro_id) WHERE reg_id ';
                        ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'reg_ans' THEN
                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' reg_answers WHERE reg_ans_frn_reg_id ';
                        ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'tvl_ans' THEN
                            dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' tvl_answers WHERE tvl_ans_frn_reg_id ';
                        END IF;

                        IF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'pro_ans' THEN  
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || '= ' || CAST(temp_reg AS VARCHAR) || ');';
                        ELSE
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || '= ' || CAST(temp_reg AS VARCHAR) || ';';
            END IF;
```

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

I am sorry to know what do you want, but this can run...

Comment: At Last This dyn_sql contains a Update Query as per the If and Else condition , I want to execute this update query.

Comment: It seems that you forget to declare the type of dyn_sql and  'END IF;' statement at the end of the last if ...

Comment: Srry for my posting it is working and thanks a lot for directing me to my mistake.